# What does that mean when a German said 'nasty beast' to you?

Tags: slang, joke

A German friend said this to me once. Does *nasty beast* have special meaning in German language?

Comment: Did the friend say that in english or german?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that's what they said? It's quite possible you misheard them (it is very common to hear similar sounding words in your native language instead of the actual words when hearing unfamiliar terms from other languages), although if this was supposed to be a german term I can't tell which one it could've been.

Comment: @Cubic  wild guess: “nass’ bist” with a tinge of dialect?

Comment: @Stephie  Könnte auch sein: Treffen sich zwei Ladendiebe im Supermarkt. Sagt der eine: "**Na, stibitzt** du wieder was?"

Answer (score 2):

No, *nasty beast* is an English phrase that has no special German meaning apart from the meaning it has in English.